# How can i detect the children element is overflowed the parent (top, left, right and bottom) in jquery?

Tags: jquery-ui

```
var element = document.querySelector(parent);

if((element.offsetHeight < element.scrollHeight) || (element.offsetWidth < element.scrollWidth)) {
    element.style.borderColor = "Red";
}
else {
    element.style.borderColor = "white";
}
```

this solution  only detect the right and bottom. I need to detect the all side overflow status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres the working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/SbhqG/4/

```
var p = $('#parent');
var c = $('#child');
var p_o = p.offset();
var c_o = c.offset();
var p_o_right = parseInt(p_o.left + p.width(), 10);
var p_o_bottom = parseInt(p_o.top + p.height(), 10);
var c_o_right = parseInt(c_o.left + c.width(), 10);
var c_o_bottom = parseInt(c_o.top + c.height(), 10);

$(function () {
    if (p_o.top > c_o.top || p_o_right < c_o_right || p_o_bottom < c_o_bottom || p_o.left > c_o.left) {
        alert('child overflows');
    } else {
        alert('child inside');
    }
});
```

Just edit the top,left and width,height CSS property to test the child element inside the parent:

```
#child {
    top: 10px;
    left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: If the parent has multiple children this check the first children only. I need to check all children status. How can i do this? My Fiddle: jsfiddle.net/mpanuraj/SbhqG/5